# if I changed app graphics for iphone 5 , is it going to work for iphone 4, 3GS properly

Tags: iphone, ios

if I changed app graphics for iphone 5 , is it going to work for iphone 4, 3GS properly or the users have to resize the app like when you download iphone app in iPad ?

Comment: This question is too open ended to answer reasonably. Which graphics are you referring to. Are we talking fullscreen images or just images for custom controls etc. -> it entirely depends on your app.

Comment: full screen , like background for the whole app

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you are using both normal sized images and 2x images for retina display, you won't have a problem on older devices.

They'll just pickup the regular sized images while the ones with retina display will load the @2x ones.

What you *do* have to take into account is that if you don't include regular sized images (if you only use @2x images), older devices **won't** load them.

Answer (score 0):

@2X will still work. However I did download xcode 4.5 with iOS 6 Gold Master seeds and played with it last night. The splash screen will include the new slightly higher resolution image 11??x640 as well as the 960x640 and 480x360.

Answer (score 0):

For fullscreen images, you will have to supply at least two versions, better three.

One being 640 × 1136, one being 640 x 960 and one being 320 x 480.

For the 3.5" retina version, you may use the automatic selection (aka @2x). For the former 4" retina version it appears as if you will have to include your own code to select the right one.

Comment: You're saying they haven't included the same system as the @2x for the new iPhone ? I understand it would be way more complex but this is going to take a **lot** of rewriting...

Comment: You certainly may do that but that will be scaled depending on the autoresizing masks of the view that shows it (e.g. UIImageView).

Comment: I meant they did not implement something like *@something* for the new iPhone. Of course I understand you can use stretched @2x images, but I thought they would have done something similar with the new resolution...

Comment: No, there is no such thing known so far.